# Use GitHub username and not profile name for commit messages

Tags: github, commit, commit-message

The GitHub account username is e.g mojombo and the profile-name ist Tom Preston-Werner: https://github.com/mojombo

Is there a way to make GitHub use the username and not the profile-name for commit-messages?

Comment: gitHub is always uses the username, isn't it? (as seen in https://github.com/30daysoflaptops/30daysoflaptops.github.io/commit/e2c559d49301af3c03c5d8b382d79ec982449aa8 for example)

Comment: GitHub just checks the email-address and not the commit-author name to associate a commit with a GitHub user.
If you commit on GitHub, however, it uses the profile name:
commit e2c559d49301af3c03c5d8b382d79ec982449aa8 Author: Tom Preston-Werner <tom@mojombo.com>